# Add a new row on XML file

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file

I have an XML file.
I want to add a new row to the XML with a batch script.

An example of the xml file is:

```
<MyXML flag="0">
     <MyRow Path="C:\a.txt" DisplayName="a"/> 
     <MyRow Path="C:\b.txt" DisplayName="b"/> 
</MyXML>
```

After run the batch file:
:

```
 <MyXML flag="0">
     <MyRow Path="C:\a.txt" DisplayName="a"/> 
     <MyRow Path="C:\b.txt" DisplayName="b"/> 
     <MyRow Path="C:\c.txt" DisplayName="c"/> 
</MyXML>
```

How can i do it with batch script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to parse XML *as* XML, rather than as predictably formatted flat text to hack and scrape.  Here's a very basic batch + PowerShell hybrid script that'll demonstrate exactly what you asked for.

```js
<# : batch portion
@echo off
setlocal

set "xmlfile=test.xml"

powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
goto :EOF

: end batch / begin PowerShell #>

[xml]$xml = gc $env:xmlfile
$add = $xml.createElement('MyRow')
$add.setAttribute('Path', 'C:\c.txt')
$add.setAttribute('DisplayName', 'c')
$xml.MyXML.appendChild($add)
$xml.Save($env:xmlfile)
```

... Or if you prefer a batch + JScript hybrid:

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
setlocal

set "xmlfile=test.xml"

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%xmlfile%"
goto :EOF

@end // end batch / begin JScript

var xml = WSH.CreateObject('MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0');
xml.load(WSH.Arguments(0));
var add = xml.createElement('MyRow');
add.setAttribute('Path', 'C:\\c.txt');
add.setAttribute('DisplayName', 'c');
xml.selectSingleNode('//MyXML[@flag=0]').appendChild(add);
xml.save(WSH.Arguments(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

with [replacer.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/replacer.bat):

```
call replacer.bat "e?xml.txt" "</MyXML>" "\t<MyRow Path=\u0022C:\\c.txt\u0022 DisplayName=\u0022c\u0022/>\r\n</MyXML>"
```

`e?` is for evaluation of special characters like new lines,tabs and so on.Qor quotes unicode escapes are used.
Though with such jscript/batch hybrids is possible to use xml parsers I have no ready to use scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This *Full BAT* will only work if the xml is not ***all in one line***.

I posted this code even if I find the 2 others solutions more secure in all case.

```
@echo off
set "$File=test.xml"
set "$NewRow=MyRow Path="C:\c.txt" DisplayName="c"/"
set "$Balise=/MyXML"

(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "%$File%') do (
   echo "%%a" | find /i "<%$Balise%" >nul && (
      echo      ^<%$NewRow%^> 
      echo ^<%$Balise%^>) || echo %%a
 )
)>Output.xml

move "Output.xml" "%$File%
del "Output.xml" 2>nul
```

Comment: @SacheDee, I'm trying to run the .bat file but i got error "| was unexcepted at this time"